# Get ajax result in different divs if success or error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I currently have my jQuery outputting the result in the same div as per error or success:

HTML

```
     <div id="error-message").html(res);
```

JQUERY

```
     jQuery('#register-me').on('click',function(){
       $("#myform").hide();
       jQuery('#loadingmessage').show(); 
       var action = 'register_action';
       var username = jQuery("#st-username").val();
       var mail_id = jQuery("#st-email").val();
       var firname = jQuery("#st-fname").val();
       var lasname = jQuery("#st-lname").val();
       var passwrd = jQuery("#st-psw").val();
       var ajaxdata = {
          action: 'register_action',
          username: username,
          mail_id: mail_id,
          firname: firname,
          lasname: lasname,
          passwrd: passwrd,
       }
       jQuery.post( ajaxurl, ajaxdata, function(res){
          $('#loadingmessage').hide();
          $("#myform").show();
          jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
       });
     });
```

PHP

```
$error = '';
$uname = trim( $_POST['username'] );
$email = trim( $_POST['mail_id'] );
$fname = trim( $_POST['firname'] );
$lname = trim( $_POST['lasname'] );
$pswrd = $_POST['passwrd'];

if( empty( $_POST['username'] ) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Username</p>';
if( empty( $_POST['mail_id'] ) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Email Id</p>';
elseif( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Valid Email</p>';

if( empty( $_POST['passwrd'] ) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Password should not be blank</p>';

if( empty( $_POST['firname'] ) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter First Name</p>';
elseif( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$fname) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Valid First Name</p>';

if( empty( $_POST['lasname'] ) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Last Name</p>';
elseif( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$lname) )
  $error .= '<p class="error">Enter Valid Last Name</p>';

if( empty( $error ) ){
  $status = wp_create_user( $uname, $pswrd ,$email );

  if( is_wp_error($status) ){
     $msg = '';
     foreach( $status->errors as $key=>$val ){
        foreach( $val as $k=>$v ){
           $msg = '<p class="error">'.$v.'</p>';
        }
     }
     echo $msg;
  } else {
     $msg = '<p class="success">Registration Successful</p>';
     echo $msg;
  }
} else {
   echo $error;
}
  die(1);
}
}
```

I'm getting confused on how to get the results in 2 different places.

1: Error = display errors and show the form, ideally errors should be displayed below each form field, at the moment is a div on top of the form

2: Success = hide the form, display only the success msg

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: why don't you just do the validation client side before you do the ajax request

Comment: @Pekka웃 at the moment the result is displayed in the same div for both error and success, i can't figure out how to get different result on different html places

Comment: @Armand i have tried the validation plugin without any success, also the php is already checking for errors, if you ask me, i completly agree with you. I'd be glad for some help

Comment: the problem with your current code is that it will append the result from the php as one set of data, one thing you can try is instead of echo on each error create an array of errors and serialize it to JSON with key value, where the key then can be the element where you want to display the error message's id and the value the message to display, you can the in the javascript loop through the array and just append the html

Comment: @Armand but rather than do a whole re-structure of the js, shall I not just make it so it outputs it in 2 different places in html with that php? Dunno, just asking..

Comment: @rob.m yes, but you said you wanted to display the errors next to the form fields, i am busy typing a solution

Comment: @rob.m see the answer by Dr.Flink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**METHOD 1**
If you would like to have an error message per validated field then:
You have a form input, for example:

```
<input name="myfield" id="myfield" type="text">
```

Next to it, you can add a div or span with your alert/error message and appropriate id, something like:

```
<input name="myfield" id="myfield" type="text">
<span id="myfield_Error" class="none">Please fill this field</span>
```

Where class="none" in your css, is used to hide the error container. Something like:

```
.none {display:none;}
```

Now for your jquery part:

```
var myfield= $("#myfield").val();
if (myfield=='') { $("#myfield_error").show(); }
```

The trick here is to named your error containers in a similar way as your target form element you validate. So for id="fieldA" you will have the error id="fieldA_error".

**EDIT1**:
If you need to use classes, you need to modify a little the code.
You need to form an array of element to check.
Loop through the array.
And use somethign like:

```
var fieldName = $(this).attr('name');
var fieldVallue = $(this).val();
if (fieldVallue=='') 
{ 
  $("#"+fieldName+"_error").show(); 
} 
else 
{ 
  $("#"+fieldName+"_error").hide; 
}
```

**Method 2**
If you just like to have 2 different containers, one for success and one for error/failed validation, then you need to output something different from your php file.
So your php file can output someting like:

```
$report['status'] = 'error'
$report['message'] = 'error in xxxx field - please use a proper email'
echo json_encode($report);
```

Then in your ajax success you can check what response you got. You parse your json response and based on your 'status', you put your 'message' in different containers

I hope this is what you look for.

Comment: method 1 just look so easy and perfect as it doens't need much changes, thanks a lot

Comment: should use .myField rather than the id as we can't have more than 1 id

Comment: @rob.m check my edit please. Hope this approach suits you better.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can assign an error handler as follow

```
var jqxhr = jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl,
    ajaxdata,
    function(res){
        $('#loadingmessage').hide();
        $("#myform").show();
        jQuery("#error-message").html(res);
    }
).fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

and send a non-2xx code from your php code (with [http_response_code](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)) if it doesn't validate.

Comment: ha! .fail completly ignored it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Encode result array in JSON format and return the response.

```
<?php

if ($validation==false)
{
    $result = array ('response'=>'error','message'=>'Some validation error');  
}
else
{
    $result = array ('response'=>'success','message'=>'Success');  
}

 echo json_encode($result);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.response == 'error') {
            alert('error');
        } else if (data.response == 'success') {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('sorry there was an error');
        }
    }

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: that changes the way I have built the code tho, it'd be better if I could have the same check but in php which I have but just output the result in 2 different places

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to return (for example) JSON to the front end instead of one string. The JSON would containt key/value pairs in the form of ID => Message.

For example:

```
$errors = array();

if( empty( $_POST['passwrd'] ) ) {
  $errors['st-psw'] = "Password should not be blank";
} 

if( empty( $_POST['firname'] ) ) {
  $errors['st-fname'] = 'Enter First Name';
} elseif( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'-]+$/",$fname) ) {
  $errors['st-fname'] = 'Enter Valid First Name';
}

...
...

if( empty( $errors ) ){
  $response['success'] = true;
} else {
  $response['success'] = false;
  $response['errors'] = $errors;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Then you will loop the JSON object in your javascript and insert the error messages after each target.

Comment: i see, that's actually nice. Thanks